# String equality, ignore case?

Tags: elisp

**Q:** how does one test string equality but ignore case?

I've got a situation in which I'd like to compare strings but ignore case.  Case is significant for `string-equal`, and apparently is insensitive to `case-fold-search`:

```
(string-equal "string" "StrinG")        ; => nil
(let ((case-fold-search t))
  (string-equal "string" "StrinG"))     ; => nil
```

I could always preprocess the strings (say, with `downcase`) before comparing them:

```
(string-equal (downcase "string")
              (downcase "StrinG"))      ; => t
```

But that seems like overkill to do two extra function calls every time.  Have I overlooked the relevant predicate function somewhere?

Comment: I used compare-strings and found the following problem.
(setq str "title") (cond (compare-strings str "authortitle") do something.) (compare-strings str "title") do something else.) The first compare-strings returns a positive value implying true which is not what I want. Therefore I used the downcase suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `compare-strings`:

```
(compare-strings STR1 START1 END1 STR2 START2 END2 &optional IGNORE-CASE)
```

Use `nil`s for starts and ends to use the whole strings.

Answer (score 8):

Another short alternative:

```
(cl-equalp "string" "strinG")      ; => t
(cl-equalp "strinG" "this string") ; => nil 
(cl-equalp "word" "buzzword")      ; => nil
```

`equalp` from the deprecated `cl` library is another alternative.
From `(documentation 'cl-equalp)`, my emphasis in bold:

> like ‘equal’, except that it accepts numerically equal numbers of
> different types (float vs. integer), and also compares strings
> **case-insensitively**.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`string-suffix-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Comparison.html):

```
(string-suffix-p "string" "strinG" t)
```

Much simpler and doesn't require 4 `nil`s. It doesn't test if strings are equal *per se* (`(string-suffix-p "word" "buzzword" t) ⇒ t`). Although, in some cases this should be sufficient (if you have limited dictionary to check upon).

Comment: `(string-suffix-p "strinG" "this string" t)` also returns `t`. This is not what the OP wants. I suggest you either modify or delete this answer.

Comment: Answer updated. I will leave it because `string-{prefix,suffix}-p` can useful in many ways: test if word at point is given keyboard (in SQL for example where case can be mixed) etc.